# In Flex 3 Using a List Component

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

How do I have one a background image for each list object and a different background image on rollover.

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom item renderer for the list. Then make a rollOver handler that switches out the image on rollover.

[Flex Quick Start: Building an advanced user interface](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/using_item_renderers/)